# Echo PHP Date if past a certain time EST

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am running online trainings at 6m EST every day, and I want that to be listed on my website, without having to go in every day and change the code.

Currently, I am simply displaying "tomorrow's" date regardless of when someone gets onto the page:

```
<?php echo(date( 'l, M j', time()+86400 ) );?> / 6pm EST
```

However, I want to make it so that it displays todays date until it gets to 6pm EST, then it displays tomorrows date until midnight EST when it goes back to todays date.

ie. It displays today until the training starts at 6pm, then it displays the next training.

I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm not great at PHP

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Today
$timestamp = time();

// If after 6pm, add a day
if (date('H') >= 18) {
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}

// Display
echo(date( 'l, M j', $timestamp));
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/p9OSXBx1

Or the one-liner:

```
echo date('l, M j', strtotime(date('H') > 17 ? '+1 day' : 'now'));
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/xt978RbY

Comment: its the pesky planet not behaving itself at fault. :-)\